# When is it appropriate to use "to receive someone"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In what cases we can use the verb *receive* to refer to a person and not to an object?

Comment: In this context, it means to welcome them (into your home, for example), or in general to allow the person access to you (the queen received the envoy for an audience).

Comment: Which dictionaries have you checked in, Veselin? The AHDEL, for instance, lists 18 senses for 'receive', with the types of referents that each transitive sense can describe with a DO.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be used in the case of radio communication. "How do you receive me?" "Receiving you loud and clear."

Comment: Do take a look at upvoted answers on the site to see the sort of thing which is considered good. The system has flagged this answer as of low quality -- and while anyone who knows the idiomatic use of *receive* here would understand the answer, it could usefully be explained.

Comment: Is it a possible meaning? And a obvious one?

Answer (score 1):

"To receive" can refer to having a guest.  However, using the verb in reference to a person implies great formality.  Kings or presidents "receive" ambassadors or other visitors on official business.  Unless you are a member of the upper aristocracy or a senior government official, use of the word might sound a tad pretentious in reference to having guests even for a formal dinner.

Comment: In a business context, how might I express to a client "we would be more than happy to receive you." without sounding pretentious?